# Centos 8 (Kernel 4.18): Max. size for dma_alloc_coherent

Tags: centos, dma

In centos8.0.1905 (kernel 4.18) I modified kernel configuration to: CONFIG_CMA=y, CONFIG_DMA_CMA=y
In kernel boot parameters I added:  cma=64M@512M

In my device driver I have to allocate a 64MB physically contiguous buffer for DMA. 
I tried calling:

dma_addr_t dma_handle;
void *p = dma_alloc_coherent(pDev, BUF_SIZE, &dma_handle, GFP_KERNEL)

But the max. size of BUS_SIZE for which I got p!=0 is 0x400000 (4MB). 
Can you please explain what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

In recompiled the kernel with CONFIG_CMA=y, CONFIG_DMA_CMA=y
and booted this kernel with cma=512M

In the device driver, before calling to **dma_alloc_coherent** I called to
rc=dma_set_mask_and_coherent (pPciDev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64));
and checked that rc=0.

Thank you,
Zvika